# Convert grease pencil to mesh in 2.8?

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil

I've watched some tutorials about grease pencil in blender 2.8 by Jama Jurabaev and other blenderers, and I wanted to do the same thing.

But now I have a problem. When I have done drawing and want to convert the lines to curve, there's no "convert to curve" option although they(Jama) easily find it when they hit f3 and type "convert to..." or something.

Of course I did the same thing, but I couldn't find it.
I appreciate it if somebody has any idea.

edit:Thanks for your answer! But I still can't find it in the contextual menu.... What on earth is wrong with my blender? I'm in object mode and selecting the stroke object.

[image: here's my state of interface]

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you're in **Object mode**, with the stroke object selected.

Nowadays, the conversion tools are in the contextual menu:
[image: demo pic]

If you use Left click select, you can open this menu via right-click on the stroke object. Otherwise, you need to hit the <kbd>W</kbd> key.

For now, using the mesh conversion on a stroke object results to a curve object for some reason, I guess it will be fixed. If you get that issue, simply redo the same thing on the curve object.

Comment: You're lucky I visited this thread again and read your subject, I wouldn't have seen your edit otherwise. Post a new comment next time, so that we get a notification.
Try downloading the latest build of blender 2.8.