# Is there a way to make Paint3D's hand drawn soft edge shapes in Blender?

Tags: modeling, grease-pencil

In paint 3D there is a tool that allows you to hand draw a shape and paint 3D will convert it into mesh with soft edges, is there a way to recreate this workflow in blender?
[image: Hand drawn 2D outlines converted to mesh]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127665/convert-grease-pencil-to-mesh-in-2-8